# Outlook add-in reloading

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I'm trying to reload add-in to handle my own update runtime (using click once deployment API, but to provide silend updates)

But I've stucked on reloading add-in. My current task is just simple unload and reload add-in. What I found was similar to this:

```
private void Reload()
    {
        try
        {
            COMAddIns comAddIns = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.COMAddIns;
            COMAddIn addIn =
                comAddIns.Cast<COMAddIn>().FirstOrDefault(addin => string.Equals(addin.Description, "OutlookAddIn1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

            if (addIn != null)
            {
                addIn.Connect = false;
                addIn.Connect = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

But this simple crashes on:

```
addIn.Connect = false;
```

I tried put this inside additonal try/catch block but it is not working. While calling 
`Connect = false` I have `ThreadAbortException`, that I cannot prevent to happen.

I would simple disable and enable add-in from code, at this moment which I cannot achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK that is not possible since `Connect = false` tells the hosting runtime to throw your thread away... you could deliver 2 AddIns (the real one and a second which strictly handles the update only, each AddIn could handle the update of the other one for example)...